# Emoji works in a site but not in the other site on the same host

Tags: 7, database

I am trying to enable emojis following [Multi-byte UTF-8 support in Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/2754539).

I have added the following to the settings.php file.

```
  'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
  'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
```

I've converted MySQL tables into utf8mb4 format and set the collate to utf8mb4_general_ci.

On the Drupal 8 site emojis work, while on the Drupal 7 I get the following error.

> 4 byte UTF-8 for mysql is activated, but not supported on your system. Please turn this off in settings.php, or ensure that all database-related requirements are met.

What am I missing?

Update

When I try to save a node with an emoji I receive the following error.

```
StatusText: Service unavailable (with message)
ResponseText: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: &#039;\xF0\x9F\x98\x8A&#039;
```

Comment: What's your D7's core version?

Comment: @NoSssweat Thanks for replying, 7.69.

Answer (score 1):

First I SUGGEST to take a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/utf8mb4_convert module

try to adding   `'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
  'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',` configs to your `settings.php` file.

after adding it should be something like :

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'databasename',
  'username' => 'username',
  'password' => 'password',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
  'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
);
```

if it does not work for you, probably you need to change MySQL configs. use the following config in your MySQL configuration ( usually `my.cnf` or `my.ini`)

```
# Use UTF8MB4 as the character set
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
character-set-server = utf8mb4
```

another suggestion:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci;
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', TABLE_NAME,'` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;') AS mySQL
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA= "dbname"
AND TABLE_TYPE="BASE TABLE"
```

FINAL STEP to make the warning go away and get a clean Status Report:

```
USE YOURDATABASENAME;INSERT INTO variable SET name='drupal_all_databases_are_utf8mb4', value='b:1;';
```

**my.ini or my.cnf**
add:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_large_prefix=true
innodb_file_format=barracuda
innodb_file_per_table=true
```

**settings.php**

```
  'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
  'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I havent used the module as I do not have Drush,  but have done all the rest. I get the the same error on my Status Report even though I have ran the query 'INSERT INTO variable SET name='drupal_all_databases_are_utf8mb4', value='b:1;';' Which shows in my database.